# How do I add the LaunchPad Icon to the Dock after upgrading fom Snow Leopard to Mavericks?

Tags: dock, macos

I have upgraded a Snow Leopard system to Mavericks. I expected to see the LaunchPad icon (spaceship icon used to launch installed apps) on the Dock, but it is not there.

How do I add that icon? I have it on a Lion system and I also see screenshots of Mavericks that have it so I don't think it's gone.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `Launchpad.app` is located in your `/Application` Folder.

You can either

- navigate with the Finder to your `/Application` Folder and drag it to your dock
- search `Launchpad.app` in Spotlight and CMD+Click the App. Your Finder will open and you can drag the App to your dock

Comment: Sorry, it seems I had my blinders on. I looked in the Application folder before I asked the question and it was not there. I looked again later and it was there.